# sendMessage not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension. I'd be glad if someone can help.

**Objective:** When you click the button in extension popup (popup.html), the title of current webpage is displayed in div (with id 'div1').

**Problem:** I have searched internet for doing this and found that passing message can be used to achieve the same. So I tried my hands on it. But its not working. I want to know what went wrong.

**Status:**

= The extension is successfully imported in chrome.

= when extension icon is clicked, it shows proper popup.

= when button is clicked nothing happens.

= developer console shows no error.

**Files:**

## =====================================

```
 //manifest.json
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "some_name_extension",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js", "content_script.js"]
        }
      ],
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
       }
    }
```

=====================================

```
<!-- popup.html -->
<! doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">
    </script>
    <style>
        html
        {
            height: 200;
            width: 200;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn1">
        click me!
    </button>
    <div id="div1">
        (title will be displayed here)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

=====================================

```
//content_script.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var title1=document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(sender=="popup")
    {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage(title1,"content","1");
    }
   });
 });
```

=====================================

```
//popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var mainBtn = document.getElementById('btn1');
    mainBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage("button_clicked","popup","1");
    });

    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

    function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(sender=="content")
        {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=msg;
        }
    } 
   );
 });
```

## =====================================

link to jquery script file : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` (plural) not `getElementByTagName`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! I made the correction. But it does not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sender` is an object that's set by the browser automatically, not a string that you can pass yourself. Use the devtools debugger to inspect your code and variables by setting breakpoints inside the callbacks, don't write the code blindly.
2. There's no need to check the `sender` in this case because content scripts cannot message each other anyway.
3. The correct method of sending a message to a content script from the popup is [chrome.**tabs**.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) with `tabId` as the first parameter:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
       action: 'setTitle', 
       title: title1,
     });
   });
   ```
4. To send many values at once use an object: `{action: 'setTitle', title: title1}` or `{action: 'buttonClicked', data: 1}` and so on.
5. `chrome.extension` is deprecated for messaging, use `chrome.runtime`
6. Your code doesn't use jQuery so there's no need to inject it in manifest.json

Comment: Thanks a lot @wOxxOm! However I had to use a response function to get the answer to other end. Is there any way to do that without it?

Means how do I receive the message on other end using

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    action: 'setTitle', 
    title: title1,
  });
});

Comment: @N_X41, what is a "response function"? Why using it is a problem? You already have onMessage listener in the content script. Make sure you've reloaded the web page because content scripts aren't automatically reinjected when you reload your extension.

Comment: This is how am getting back response.
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'setTitle', 
    title: title1,}, function(response) {
    // do something with response
  });
});
.There is no problem with it, just wanted to know, what approach you were suggesting. Anyways it's working fine now! Thanks for pointing in right direction ;)